# How to create user defined type (string, int, so on) template class object C++

Tags: c++, templates

I am struggling with allowing the user to select data type template will be created as. Since template type must be defined on compile, I must specify data type template will use eg(string, int, so on), but that means I cannot change it later on, from lets say string to int even if my template supports it because template class object was declared as a string.

Comment: Sounds like an [XY probmem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You can't do what you're asking for. You need a different approach to solve your real problem.

Comment: [You are asking about the Y you believe to solve X](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Modify the interactive prompt to use templates in the following way:
• Before asking for the starting capacity, prompt the user to specify what data type they want the vector to store in data
o 1 for int
o 2 for float
o 3 for double
o 4 for string
o 5 for bool

Comment: allowing user to select data type template will be created as

Comment: @Knight Sounds like you want [std::variant](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant)

Comment: What kind of code are you expecting to run on both `int` and `std::string`? What are you trying to do here?

Comment: You already know that selecting the template data type at run-time is impossible so we are asking you to explain **why** you want to do that so that we may be able to offer other solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Note that your instructions do not call for *changing* the type, only that the user can select it upfront.

You can solve this with templates (of course).

A trivial example:

```
template<typename T>
void interact()
{
    std::vector<T> collection;
    std::cout << "Enter five things\n";
    while (collection.size() < 5)
    {
        std::string input;
        if (std::cin >> input)
        {
            std::istringstream iss(input);
            T value {};
            if (iss >> value)
            {
                collection.push_back(value);
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << "That was not a good thing. Try again.";
            }
        }
    }
    std::cout << "You gave me: ";
    for (const auto& i: collection)
    {
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    }
}

int main()
{
    for (;;)
    {
        std::cout << "What do you want you work with?\n";
        std::string selection;
        std::cin >> selection;
        if (selection == "string")
        {
            interact<string>();
            break;
        }
        else if (selection == "int")
        {
            interact<int>();
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Does not exist. Try again.\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Examples:

```
$ ./app
What do you want you work with?
int
Enter five things
1 2 3 5 5
You gave me: 1 2 3 5 5

$ ./app
What do you want you work with?
string
Enter five things
hi ho here we go
You gave me: hi ho here we go
```